# asp.net dropdown always no selected value on server side

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have an asp.net dropdown like this

```
 <asp:DropDownList width="95%" ID="RessourceComposantes" runat="server"    
       DataSourceID="Composantes" 
       DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="ComposanteID">
 </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="RessourceComposantes" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OraEntities %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Blabla], [blablabla] FROM [blablablaa] 
        ORDER BY [blablablabla]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Is it normal that when I do dd_ressource_composante.selectedvalue on the server side I have no value. It's always "".

the source looks like this :

```
     <select name="ctl00$Tab$dd_ressource_composante" id="ctl00_Tab_dd_ressource_composante" style="width:95%;">
        <option value="1">Composante</option>
        <option value="3">DGAG</option>
        <option value="2">DSF</option>
        <option value="5">Test</option>
        <option value="6">Tous</option>

        <option value="4">VMD</option>

    </select>
```

I just tried to fill my dropdown in vb.net and I have the same result. The dropdown is full but when I do a postback I have no selected value

Actualy on the server side when I put a breakpoint on the dropdown, the item count is 0. I don't understand why... It's like the 8th dropdown list in this project and everything is the same but this one doesn't work.

I don't do any binding on the page load. it's all in the aspx file

well it works ONLY when I add autopostback="true" SelectedIndexChanged="dd_ressource_composante_SelectedIndexChanged" for the dropdown.

And theres no code in dd_ressource_composante_SelectedIndexChanged

It's vb.net for the server side

Thank you

Comment: Did you view the rendered source to ensure that the DataValueField actually contains a value?

Comment: try _dd_ressource_composante.selectedvalue.Text_ instead of dd_ressource_composante.selectedvalue

Comment: Do you have ViewState enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's weird. That control was in a table and I added a row like this

```
tblRessourcesProjet.Rows.Insert(1, tr)
```

and I changed it for

```
tblRessourcesProjet.Rows.Add(tr)
```

I don't understand quite well why it was a problem but it works now.
Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Where are you calling your dd_ressource_composantes.DataBind() method in the code-behind?  Is it in the Page_Load event?  If so, have you wrapped that statement in an IsPostback check so that you're not binding it everytime the page loads?  Not doing so would reset your DataSource, and any selected value, every time the page posts back.

```
If (Not Page.IsPostBack) Then
    dd_ressource_composantes.DataBind()
End If
```

NOT

```
' No IsPostBack check
dd_ressource_composantes.DataBind()
```

Comment: SelectedValue still returns "". Sorry

Comment: Also, please post where you are actually trying to retrieve SelectedValue

Comment: All the code is there. I'm gonna try to do the binding the way im used to in vb.net in the aspx.vb file

Answer (score 1):

Also, doesn't your DataSourceID have to be "RessourceComposantes" and not "Composantes" since that's the ID of your datasource?

Comment: I was so sure that you were right but it doesn't work :( thank you

Comment: Did you try calling dd_ressource_composantes.DataBind() in the code-behind? It's possible that it's not binding the control automatically.

Comment: Now, no matter what I select I have "1". that's a good start :P

Comment: Are you using a button to post back your values? If not, to have the selected value automatically register, you will have to enable AutoPostBack property of the dropdown, because when you select a new dropdown value in the browser, it has to send the data back to the server where you are checking the value. Try enabling the AutoPostBack property and then check it once it posts back to the server.

Comment: Also try to create an event handler for the dd_ressource_composantes.SelectedIndexChanged event (go into Page_Load, type in "dd_ressource_composantes.SelectedIndexChanged += " then press TAB twice, it will create the event handler automatically for you -- IF you're using Visual Studio) and check the value in that event.

Comment: Can you post your entire .aspx and .aspx.cs file?

Comment: Only reason I can think of why it's not even going inside the event is that either it's not detecting that the SelectedIndex changed. You could try rebinding the DropDownList on every page load, not sure if it will work but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

When setting `SelectedValue`, the value must match the value of the `Value` attribute. If that's not the case, the results are, for all intents and purposes, undefined.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I'm trying to get the value with SelectedValue

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the selected value, or the selected text? The question is rather vague.

Comment: Sorry. Im trying to get the value.

Comment: What do you get when you inspect the control's `SelectedIndex` property? Is it -1? If it's not -1, try retrieving `list.Items[list.SelectedIndex].Value`. (Replacing list with your control's name, naturally.)

Comment: That explains why you're getting "". There's no item selected. Now you need to do some research. Why is there no selected item? THat's the real question.

Comment: When I add autopostback="true" SelectedIndexChanged="dd_efforts_composantes_SelectedIndexChanged" for the dropdown, it works. The event does nothing.. It looks like a postback problem. I have no ideas lol.

Comment: Which event isn't working? What event did you expect to work correctly? Page_Load?

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling `DataBind()` method somewhere in your page_load event please comment that otherwise wrap it in

```
 IF NOT IsPostBack Then
   DataBind()
 EndIF
```

`This problem is most likely caused by rebinding the control before the event you are using is fired`. If you are getting the selectedItem.Text the SelectedValue should also be there.